# How can I create tables dynamically in Django admin panel

Tags: django, database, django-models, django-admin

i want to make a table for each event automaticly ,each table contains the participants of this event

the result should look like this :

[image]

models.py:

```
class Student(models.Model):
    email        = models.EmailField(unique=True)
    phone        = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True)
    first_name   = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
    last_name    = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
    gender       = models.BooleanField(default=1 ) 
    ...
    
  


class Event(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    poster = models.ImageField(upload_to=get_poster_image_path,null=True,blank=True,default="events\posters\default.png")
    description = models.TextField(null=True,blank=True)
    event_date = models.DateField(null=True,blank=True)
    ...
    registrations = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)



class EventParticipant(models.Model):
    event = models.ForeignKey(Event, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    participant = models.ForeignKey(student, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    join_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True,null=True,default=timezone.now)
    ...
```